# Hyper-V Replication without Domain

Tags: ssl, domain, hyper-v, replication, workgroup

I have a hyper-V host in a different DC that I want TWO source servers to replicate to.

I have followed guides such as https://michaelfirsov.wordpress.com/hyper-v-replica-in-windows-server-2016-configuring-certificate-based-authentication-part1/ for one to one server, but I can't seem to work out if it's possible for two servers on a workgroup to replicate to the same server using SSL certificates.

Anyone got any idea if this is possible?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but found the following guide. Might be helpful: https://the-server.ninja/2015/05/13/enable-hyper-v-replication-between-two-workgroup-servers/
I am not sure it works, however, worth checking. More info: https://www.hyper-v.io/hyper-v-replica/
What do you mean by "same server" ? Do you want to have to separate servers replicate to third as a replica target?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to configure Server 2019 for replication in workgroup mode.

I followed the steps from https://michaelfirsov.wordpress.com/hyper-v-replica-in-windows-server-2016-configuring-certificate-based-authentication-part1/ but with the exception of changing the DNS Suffix of the machine.

I also configured the certificate without a FQDN, just created the certificate with the server name and it worked like a charm.

Thank you to Michael Firsov for the article.

Comment: could you please answer in a way to add the required content and use the links as a reference? ATM its just NOT an answer IMHO.